# Salesforce SMS solution

Tags: sms, text, sendsmsactivity

Is there a free salesforce native text messaging tool that can send sms to the person from salesforce? I did some research and found a few that we ll have to buy.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know your complete use case but [Mobile Connect](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.mc_moc_mobileconnect.htm&type=5) is a good starting point. If you want to learn see this [trailhead](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/sms-messaging-with-mobileconnect) module. My recommendation would be you should touch base with your customer success team to get the optimized use case specific recommendation there are multiple way to cater SMS requirement.

Answer (score 0):

You can check these free SMS apps [ClickSend SMS](https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N3A00000EFoE5UAL&tab=e), [SMS for Salesforce](https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N3000000B3gjEEAR&legacy=true) available on AppExchange, Also there are paid tools available like [Mogli SMS](https://www.salesforceben.com/send-and-receive-sms-with-salesforce/), [360 SMS App](https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N3000000DpSyIEAV&channel=sponsored-search&tab=e) etc., and many more tools are available based on youre requirement.